# Performance-Billion Counter

Tags: java, android, performance

Recently I developed a billion counter application to measure phone's performance.

I used the following code to measure taken to count to a billion.

```
Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            count = 1000000000;
            while (count != 0){
                --count;
            }

            t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            tf = (t2-t1)/1000;

            CountDisp.setText(""+tf);
        }
    });
```

My phone took (approx)75 seconds to count to a billion using this code.

But when I measured the time from another application downloaded from Google Play Store , my phone took 37 seconds to count to a billion.

**How can I make my code as fast as possible?**

**Or is there an another way of doing this?**

**NOTE:- Both the applications took same time to count to a million, (approx)0.110 seconds**

Comment: Without the other application's code it's not really possible to tell why one took longer than the other.

Comment: That is a very slow phone. My oldest phone takes 60 seconds for that and a new octa core less than three. Try with 'count--'.

Comment: @resueman you mean, that app is giving fake value? please note, its not exact 37 seconds always. value varies by some milli seconds

Comment: I've added something to make the question more objective. This should avoid close-votes for being a primarily opinion-based question.

Comment: Or try `while (--count > 0 ){}`. Is count a long? How come you don't need the L?

Comment: It can depend on data type as well.. For the same piece of code declaring count as int will be much faster than declaring count as long.

Comment: Are you sure? Hmmm i will try it.

Comment: You are right. Counting with an int variable will take half the time of one with a long. My first code was using a long so this cheap chinese octacore will now count to billion in 1.3 seconds. I can start 8 threads which are all counting to a billion and they all are finished within1.3 seconds. Starting 16 threads all are ready in 2.6 seconds. How wonderfull those cores!

Comment: For those who are interested. I also tested a Note 3 and M8 and they took nearly five seconds for the 'long' count. I wonder what is going on. They have 2.2 or 2.5 GHz processors where this octa core has 1.7 GHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faster would be:

```
int count=1000000000;
while (count--!=0)
    ;
```

Note that this uses a different structure for the loop (only one read of `count`) and it uses a local variable instead of an instance field. Using a local variable is faster because it resides in a known location on the stack, and takes only one operation for the JVM to retrieve it, whereas for an instance field, the JVM needs to look up `this` instance, and then load in the right field. For most purposes, the difference this extra step takes is utterly trivial, but your loop is so tight (i.e., content free) that the extra step is highly significant.

You might even do better with

```
long count=1000000000L;
```

since this might well be a 64-bit JVM.

(As far as the other app goes, it might be using JNI (native code), in which case nothing you do will compete. I doubt it, though.)

Comment: `since this might well be a 64-bit JVM.` I don't see how the JVM would change the way you want to init your longs.

Comment: @njzk2 A 64-bit JVM on a 64-bit arch might use 64-bit instructions for a `long` and 32-bit for an `int`. It is conceivable (though far from certain) that a 64-bit chip will do basic operations on a 64-bit value than on a 32-bit one. (This was certainly true for 16-bit operations on the 32-bit 80386, which were much slower than 32-bit ones.)

Comment: @njzk2 Ah, I wasn't changing how I was initializing the value, I was changing the type of it from `int` to `long`.

Comment: You may as well set `count=0` and leave the loop out to gain even more speed. The JVM can do your optimization, ot ot can leave it all out and I wonder why nobody proposed my optimization. ;)

Comment: @maaartinus Ah, if only all optimization problems were that easy!

Comment: @chiastic-security We were lucky to find one of the easiest!

Comment: @chiastic-security can you please explain why declaring the `count` variable local made the counting fast and that too with a huge difference.
when I declared `count` as local variable it took only 15 seconds to count.

Comment: @ShubhamBatra Added some explanation to help with that.